# Orbits and periodicity of points, the basics

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Im trying to put into practice what I've learn from the basics of dynamical systems and Im having some troubles with the proposed problems from G.Teschl ODE & Dynamical systems

Let $\phi$ be the flow of some first order autonomous system. I'm asked to prove:

1. Show that if T satisfies $\phi(T,x)=x$, the same is true for any integer multiple of T. Moreover, $T=nT(x)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.
2. Show that a point x is fixed if and only if $T(x)=0$
3. Show that x is periodic if and only if $\gamma_{+}(x) \cap \gamma_{-}(x) \neq \emptyset$ in which case $\gamma_{+}(x)= \gamma_{-}(x)$ and $\phi(t+T(x),x)=\phi(t,x)$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$. In particular, the period is the same for all points in the same orbit.

where $\gamma_{+}(x)=\{\phi(t,x):t_{x}\in (0,t_{x}^{+})\}, \gamma_{-}(x)=\{\phi(t,x):t_{x}\in (t_{x}^{-},0)\}$ are the forward and backwards orbit respectively, $T(x)=inf\{T>0: \phi(T,x)=x\}$ and a $y$ is a fixed point for $\dot x = f(x)$ if $f(y)=0$.

**My attempt:**

**For 1)** is not much of a problem cause, by propoerties of the flow we have that if $\phi(T,x)=x$ then $\phi(2T,x)=\phi(T,\phi(T,x))=\phi(T,x)=x$ then by induction we have that $\phi(nT,x)=\phi(T,x)=x$. And by the definition given above, $nT(x)=inf\{nT>0: \phi(T,x)=x\}$ we have that  and since $\phi(nT,x)=\phi(T,x)$ for continuity of the flow $nT=T$, then $T=nT(x)$.

**For 2)** I've been trying to use the fact that if x is a fixed point then $\gamma(x)=\gamma_{+}(x) \cup \{x\} \cup \gamma_{-}(x)=x$ then I tried to relate it to \phi but Its been unsuccessful.

**For 3)** I know that if x is periodic then $\phi(t+T(x),x)=\phi(t,x)$, $t \in (0,t_{x}^{+})$  but then for the backwards case I got lost.

**I understand this problems are easy** but I been having problems with the proof techinques so, any help would be really appreciated. Thanks so much in advance guys <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your finishing argument is not convincing. You have to show the existence of such an $n$, not start from it being given. You could apply that if no such $n$ exists, then there is some period smaller than $T(x)$, which is a contradiction.
2. $T(x)=0$ implies that there are periods $T_n$ with limit $T_n\to 0$ for $n\to\infty$, thus there is a dense set with $ϕ(kT_n,x)=x$. Then apply continuity.
3. $γ_+(x)∩γ_-(x)≠∅$ means that there are $t_-<0<t_+$ with $ϕ(t_-,x)=ϕ(t_+,x)$, which implies that $T(x)\ge 0$ and all that this implies.

Comment: I understood your answer, not let me check if I can write it properly. For 1 i got it. But for 2. (The other direction) If $T(x)=0$, this implies that $\phi (t+T(x)=x=\phi(t+0,x)$, and since this follows for every $t in \mathbb{R}$, then $\phi(t,x)=x \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$, which is the definition for it to be a fixed point. Is this right?

And for 3. Still not very clear to me how to prove the right direction, $x$ periodic implies $\lambda_{-} \cap \lambda_{+} \neq \emptyset$

Comment: 2. No, you can not use $T(x)=0$ directly in this way. You have to use that $T(x)$ is the infimum of the set of all positive $t$ with $ϕ(t,x)=x$. 3. I would think that $ϕ(-T(x),x)=ϕ(T(x),x)$ shows that the intersection is non-empty.